# Child process continues to run if parent dies

Tags: tty, signals, disown

I have a bash script which is executed via the GUI (lightdm).

In some line during the script, I want it to:

1. `sudo service lightdm stop` - stop the GUI
2. Take over a TTY (like `tty1` or `tty7`) using e.g.: `exec </dev/tty7 >/dev/tty7 2>&1`
   (if `agetty` controls the TTY, we can easily send it `SIGSTOP`).
   `tty7` is preferred since that while shutting down `lightdm`, it will be available.

The problem is that the bash script is a child of the `lightdm` service.
Therefore while executing `sudo service lightdm stop` - it will try to terminate my script/process.

I found out that I need to use `nohup` but I prefer to have my *already running* script/process immune to `SIGHUP`.
I've seen [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625409/how-do-i-put-an-already-running-process-under-nohup) about `disown` and `bg` but a script file isn't in interactive mode therefore I can't `bg` it. Also using `set -m` won't help because that anyway I need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in order to suspend my process (Sending SIGTSTP will suspend it but the file won't continue to run...).

What is the reliable & robust approach to solve this?
Using Ubuntu.

---

### Update 8 Oct 21:35 UTC - Replying to @countermode:

I tried:

```
trap '' HUP
service lightdm stop
```

also tried:

```
trap '' SIGHUP
service lightdm stop
```

But it failed.
I know that it failed because that after the line `service lightdm stop` I write to files some data. Those files modification time is too old (a day ago), thus it doesn't work.

I tried to catch all the signals that I thought I was missing, using:

```
trap_with_arg() {
    func="$1" ; shift
    for sig ; do
        trap "trap_handler $sig" "$sig"
    done
}
trap_handler() {
    echo -e " \n Caught signal $1 \n" >>/path_to_some_folder/_signals.txt
}
echo "" >/path_to_some_folder/_signals.txt
signals_list=""
for i in {1..64} ; do
    signals_list+="$(kill -l $i) "
done
trap_with_arg trap_handler 0 $signals_list

service lightdm stop
```

[As advised here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256644/identifying-received-signal-name-in-bash-shell-script).
All the signals which were caught are (left was first): `HUP`, `CONT`, `0`.

So I tried to:

```
trap '' 0 HUP CONT
service lightdm stop
```

But it failed as well...

---

### Update 9 Oct 08:46 UTC:

Actually the answer of @countermode works well.
I had a tiny mistake in the code so I thought it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell scripts can set their own signal handlers using the `trap` keyword. In your scenario you want to ignore SIGHUP, so you would call somewhere before terminating the ldm session

```
trap '' SIGHUP
```

where `''` (the empty string) indicates that you want to ignore SIGHUP (you would otherwise specify the signal handling code here).